# Imagem saindo fora da div no topo e no rodapé

Tags: html5, css3, bootstrap-3, div

Como faço para criar um div com bordas e posicionar  uma imagem com um valor de desconto acima dessa div saindo fora dela e logo abaixo centralizado um botão no meio da div como a imagem em anexo;

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: oque vc ja tem de codigo pronto ou tentou fazer ?

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori ainda não tenho nada preciso apenas de um exemplo cru mesmo que segue essa lógica!

Comment: imaginei, bem cara aqui o objetivo é te ajudar com problemas no código ou conceito/conhecimento não dar a resposta pronta, afinal isso seria errado para o seu aprendizado, seria bom vc dar uma estudada nas classes do bootstrap na sua documentação https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/ ou um site que eu utilizei muito https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/default.asp, antes de publicar perguntas assim de uma ollhada https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1084/como-devemos-formatar-perguntas-e-respostas?cb=1

Comment: @ViniciusShiguemori então eu já criei vários site no mercado usando bootstrap já li toda a documentação do bootstrap o problema não é este é que estou com dúvidas em como fazer o mencionado acima, conheço as políticas do fórum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Da uma olhada no código, acho que é isso que vc queria... Mas não é só para vc copiar e colar. Tenta dar uma estudada no código para ver como as coisas funcionam etc. Eu mesmo só fiz isso pq acho que uma forma para eu mesmo aprender as coisas, tenha esse maindset tb []´s

```css
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: black;
}
.container {
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
    border: 1px solid snow;
    height: 200px;
    width: 150px;
    display: flex;
    position: relative;
    justify-content: center;
}
.produto {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    margin: auto;
    background: url(https://www.placecage.com/c/100/100) no-repeat center;
}
.valor{
    position: absolute;
    top: -20px;
    left: -20px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
}
.comprar{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -20px;
    background-color: red;
    padding: 0.5em;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="valor">$000,00</div>
    <div class="produto"></div>
    <div class="comprar">comprar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Obrigado @hugocsl